# Does rsync execute commands via SSH on remote, or only use SFTP protocol?

Tags: ssh, networking, rsync, sftp

When using

```
rsync -az /home/me/ root@192.168.0.2:/backup/home/me/
```

does `rsync` need to be installed also on remote?

More precisely, does `rsync` run commands on remote via SSH (`rsync` specific commands, or `patch`, or `diff`, etc.) or does it only use SFTP commands on remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be at the remote end. From the `man` page:

> It is famous  for  its delta-transfer  algorithm,  which  reduces
> the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the
> differences between  the  source  files and  the  existing
> files in the destination.

Would it be so hard to test?

Comment: I wanted to do the test, but my remote already has `rsync`. I was a bit afraid of removing rsync on remote just to do the test, because it could break my backup scripts (let's imagine that when I reinstall it, a new version is installed with a few minor differences)

Comment: You didn't need to remove it, just change the permissions temporarily.

Comment: Or rename it for a short while

Comment: While the answer is correct, I do not think the quote really explains why plain SFTP won't do too.

Comment: Because the sftp protocol (and hence stfp-server) doesn't implement hashing as part of the data service, let alone hashing of range requests. It does provide range requests, but there is no mechanism for comparing ranges other than simply copying the data across the network.

Comment: Sure, but the quote does not say that. You should add this explanation to your answer. – Though actually, there is an extension for SFTP that supports hashing (even of file ranges). And some SFTP servers do support that. A related question: [How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848)

Comment: You're right @MartinPrikryl. So hashing, getting filesize mtime, seeking in the file and modifying only a few bytes etc. could be possible with only SFTP commands. Is there a mode in which rsync does not need to be installed on remote?

Comment: @Basj I believe there's not.